# What is the time complexity of this for-loop case?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, testing, time-complexity, analysis

I'm trying to figure out what is the time complexity of the following for-loop case.

```
double n; //n > 0 and a real number

for(double i=1; i<n; i*=(1+(1/n))){//some O(1) statements};
```

I argued with my professor that the time complexity is still O(log n). But he says it's not so I'm confused. In `for(double i=1; i<n; i*=2){//some O(1) statements};`, the time complexity is indeed O(log n). Why isn't the former the same? Please help.

Comment: just run the code yourself and check for values 2,3,4,..10 and compare, are there the same amount of iterations?

Comment: Consider the lim (1+1/n)^n for n to infinity. Does this give some insight?

Comment: @Henry The limit of course is *e*. But I'm not sure how that helps...

Comment: It means, that after `n` iterations `i` has only reached the value e. To get up to `n` more iterations are necessary (how many?). Therefore also O(log(n)) iterations are not enough to get up to `n`.

Comment: @Henry Yes, ok.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity would indeed be O(log n) if the code were like this:

```
double x; //x > 0 and a real number

for(double i=1; i<n; i*=(1+(1/x))){//some O(1) statements};
```

But as it is, the number of iterations `x` is equal to the number of times you have to multiply `1+1/n` by itself to get `n`:

```
(1+1/n)^x = n
```

So (by solving for `x`) the solution is `Θ(log(n)/log(1+1/n))`, which is `Θ(n log n)`.